# Maximal Facebook API requests per 10 minutes?

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to find out how many request you can execute using an access token (not making the user login via Facebook).

Somewhere, I read that you can perform 600 request per 10 minuts. Although, the answer from that thread was 2 years old and 600request/10 minutes seems like a small number of request.

Does anyone know how many request you can execute towards Facebook per X minutes?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are not one fixed limit. We have some fixed limits but it is much more likely that you will hit one of our dynamic limits.